# How to install tkinter *properly*?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am following *Matplotlib* of [this](http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/) tutorial. Initially I ran

> ```
> import numpy as np
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> # Compute the x and y coordinates for points on a sine curve
> x = np.arange(0, 3 * np.pi, 0.1)
> y = np.sin(x)
> ```

When I ran the following

> ```
> plt.plot(x, y)
> ```

It threw the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/media/abhisek/np/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3307, in plot
    ax = gca()
  File "/media/abhisek/np/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 950, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/media/abhisek/np/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 586, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/media/abhisek/np/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 535, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/media/abhisek/np/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 81, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/media/abhisek/np/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 89, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1818, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
    /usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6/tk8.6 /usr/share/tcltk/tk8.6 /media/abhisek/np/lib/tk8.6 /usr/local/lib/tcltk/tk8.6 /usr/local/share/tcltk/tk8.6 /usr/lib/tcltk/x86_64-linux-gnu/tk8.6 /usr/lib/tcltk/tk8.6 /usr/lib/tcltk/tcl8.6/tk8.6 /usr/lib/tk8.6 /media/abhisek/lib/tk8.6 /media/abhisek/np/library



This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.
```

I'm running `ubuntu 16.04 LTS(64 bit)` and I'm not finding any of the information found in google is usefull or may be it is just me. Can you tell how to solve this problem and what caused this problem to occur ?

Comment: Have you tried installing `tkinter` in the first place?

Comment: yeah, I fired `sudo apt-get install python-tk` to install it

Comment: try the solution in this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/472854/tkinter-not-working

Comment: @MaxPaymar I copied `/usr/share/tcltk/tk8.6` to `/usr/local/lib`, still didn't work

Comment: @MaxPaymar from the error message it is clear that it is finding `tk.tcl` file in `/usr/share/tcltk/tk8.6/`, so coping it won't work

Comment: I did `find / -iname *tk.tcl*`, looks like there is no `tk.tcl` file at all in my system. any suggestion ?